# Exclude folder/lib from VSCode suggestion ? with jsconfig.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosuggest, vscode-jsconfig

VSCode suggestions are very slow on my project, and especially my BFF snippet `c` that writes `console.log` takes 5 seconds to execute.
I can see in the suggestions that there are a lot of stuff coming from some libs I installed that I don't use that much (`faker`, `date-fns` for example) or some dependencies of some libs I installed (especially `lodash`)

I discovered the `jsconfig.json` file, which could save me here. But I have a hard time configuring the `exclude` field, so here is my question:

How would you configure it to exclude

1. every nested `node_modules` folder
2. specific `node_modules` folder such as `faker`, `lodash`, `date-fns` (and maybe more)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at the following VsCode settings:

- Files: Excludes [files.exclude]
- Files: Watcher Exclude [files.watcherExclude]
- Search: Exclude [search.exclude]